# Is there is an alternative to DynamicResource

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

Looks like there is not DynamicResource in XAML for Windows 8.1 platform.  Is there any other alternative to change resources in runtime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this blogpost](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2013/06/30/windows-8-1-xaml-new-theme-management-in-your-windows-store-apps/), I would presume that the most similar built-in substitute is [`ThemeResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn263118.aspx), though it seems to be limited to theme changes as a trigger.

*I have not tried this myself. If there actually is a better built-in alternative, I am happy to delete this answer.*